# Viewing errors in PhpStorm 6.0.3

Tags: phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm 6. It is showing me error counts as shown below:-

[image]

Can someone let me know where and how can I view the actual errors?

Comment: *(Unrelated to your actual question)* PhpStorm v6 is few years old now. If possible -- consider upgrading to the latest version (2016.3 .. which is like v13 now) -- there were quite a lot of improvements made since then in all aspects. This is especially valuable if you are working with some modern frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just click on such red marker on a scroll bar (as per your screenshot) to navigate to the line with error.
2. You can use `Navigate | Next Highlighted Error (F2)` and `Navigate | Previous Highlighted Error (Shift + F2)` to navigate between all the warnings and errors (this will exclude minor notices, spell checker marks etc)
3. Use `Code | Inspect Code...` to [inspect current file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/running-inspections.html) (or whole folder) -- [it will list ALL found issues](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/inspection-tool-window.html) in hierarchical view and will provide fixes to some of them (depends on actual Inspection).

   **Please note** that this tool window does not update automatically -- you need to re-run inspection manually to see updated results.

General info: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/code-inspection.html

Answer (score 0):

The line where the error occurred is red, so you just pass your mouse on top of the red dot in the scroll bar.